# Could a malicious Wordpress plugin steal privileged information?

Tags: php, wordpress

I thought to myself, what is preventing from people to hack Wordpress?
I mean, you can easily include the config file in a plugin and get the db settings and steal the admin username and password. And if we allready talking about it, is there a way to 100% protect the db settings?

Comment: Why would you upload a malicious plugin to your wordpress installation?

Comment: I don't use wordpress, but hopefully a malicious plugin could only steal the admin password hash from the db, not the actual password! Though I suppose it could just alter the login page and steal the password when you type it in.

Comment: I won't, but what if someone will add a bit of a code and do it?

Comment: Other people should not be able to add code to your wordpress installation. If they can, you have much bigger security problems.

Comment: I meant by adding a little code to their plugin, like include(x); or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passwords for WordPress user accounts are securely hashed with a salt, so even if a malicious plugin did access your database and sent your credentials back, they would have to brute force crack them.

Therefore, if you have a secure password and only install trusted plugins and run your site on a dedicated server where there is no shared access, you should be pretty safe.

Comment: A lot more damage can be done with the unsalted database username and password, though.

Comment: @ceejayoz Is correct.  If a plugin reads your wp-config.php file and takes DB credentials or just accesses the `$wpdb` variable and issues queries, they have more power than if they just had your WP admin credentials.  So you should make sure in that case that the MySQL user for wordpress can only access wordpress tables and nothing else to mitigate the risk.  And keep backups of your WP database and files so you can easily recover from such an event.

Answer (score 2):

As with any code, you should only install WordPress plugins from sources you trust. If you're particularly cautious and security conscious, you can always review the code first.